# How to rename a kernel module name without renaming the .ko passed to insmod?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, kernel-module

I need to rename a kernel module (the name that get displayed with lsmod) of an already existing driver without changing the name of the source file.

e.g.

```
# insmod xxx.ko
<<module loads successfully>>
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by    Tainted: P
xxx                   191527  0
#
```

- I want to rename **xxx** to **yyy**.
- Now I know that changing the name of the driver source file (when it involves a single file) changes the name of the module.
- But I don't want to change the name of a source file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rename your `obj-m` in Makefile and set dependency of `obj-m` to original module.

For example, I have file `hello.c` that contain all of my source code. But I want module to be `mynewname`.

Here is whole Makefile that does this:

```
obj-m := mynewname.o 
mynewname-objs := hello.o

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD  := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

I set `obj-m` to `mynewname.o` and make `mynewname.o` dependant on `hello.o`. After invoking make you'll get `mynewname.ko`.

Comment: Is it possible to set the module name in the module code itself (hello.c) ?

Comment: I haven't tried it but you can try to use `MODULE_ALIAS` macro to allow modprobe load your module using different name.