# How to rename a built-in linux kernel module?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to extend the built-in `xfs` module of linux kernel. Following [this SO post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module), I am now able to compile it locally. But to avoid conflict with the existing kernel xfs module, I would like to rename my extension to, say `xxfs`, without changing the name of the source files.

I've found [a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417395/how-to-rename-a-kernel-module-name), following which I changed the relevant lines in Makefile to:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_XFS_FS)            += xxfs.o
xxfs-objs                       := xfs.o
```

But I got an error saying

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/home/dev/tmp/xxfs/xfs.o', needed by '/home/dev/tmp/xxfs/xxfs.o'. Stop.
Makefile:1403: recipe for target '_module_/home/dev/tmp/xxfs' failed
make: *** [_module_/home/dev/tmp/xxfs] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic'
```

---

Environment:

Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-28-generic.

---

**EDIT**

I got the xfs kernel module source file by

1. installing the linux kernel source with `apt-get source linux-source-4.4.0`
2. copy the `linux-4.4.0/fs/xfs` to another directory (merely for easy maintenance), currently `/home/dev/tmp/xxfs`

To compile the module, I run the command `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules` from the `/home/dev/tmp/xxfs` directory, after which a `xfs.ko` will be generated in the same directory.

However after I change the following line in `Makefile`

```
obj-$(CONFIG_XFS_FS)            += xfs.o
```

to

```
obj-$(CONFIG_XFS_FS)            += xxfs.o
xxfs-objs                       := xfs.o
```

Everything else is not touched, but I am no longer able to compile the module with the same command.

Comment: And what is a name (and absolute path) of your source file?

Comment: @Tsyvarev See edit above

Comment: BTW, source files should be listed using `xxfs-y := ...` assignment, not with `xxfs-obj` one. See [Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)